# Python - trouble installing opencv on a mac (after opencv worked fine a few months ago)

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, installation

I have `opencv` installed on my mac which was working a few months ago but doesn't work anymore.

I have the following specificities. 
- OpenCV: 3.4.3.1
- Operating System / Platform: macOS 10.14
- Python 3.6.5

I tried to reload a `python script` where I used opencv. However, I got the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/ilmbase/lib/libImath-2_2.12.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.4.1_4/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.3.4.dylib
  Reason: image not found
```

I then tried to re-install opencv with the step by step explanation of [this site](https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/install-opencv-3-for-python-on-mac/) with which I successfully installed opencv for the first time.

1. determine which version of opencv I have on my machine

After having written `cd /usr/local/Cellar/opencv` and `ls` I get: `3.4.1_4 3.4.3   3.4.3_1`. So I conclude that the latest version on my machine is `3.4.3_1` which is in `/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.4.3_1/cv2.cpython-37m-darwin.so`

2. Determine the path for package in python

Then if i do the following `$ cd /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.4.3_1` and `$ cd lib`, I get (among others): `python3.7`. 
Then I do the following: 
`$ cd python3.7` and then `$ cd site-packages` and `$ pwd`, I get: `/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.4.3_1/lib/python3.7/site-packages`

3. add the cv2..so to System python

I enter then python with `$ python3` and get

```
Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 03:03:55) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

**Question N°1** Isn't it weird that it says version `3.6.5` and opencv seems to have a lib `3.7` (and no `3.6`)

type `>>> import sys` and then `>>> print(sys.path)`and get the following list:

```
['', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python36.zip',
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6', 
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', 
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
```

I then enter:

`$ ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.4.3_1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cv2.cpython-37m-darwin.so /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2.so`

4. Add OpenCV to Virtualenvs

I then add the following command:

```
$ mkdir ~/Dev
$ cd ~/Dev
$ virtualenv -p python3 newcvtest
$ cd newcvtest
$ source bin/activate
(newcvtest) $ python --version 
Python 3.6.5
$ pip install numpy
$ cd lib/python3.6/site-packages
$ ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.4.3_1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cv2.cpython-37m-darwin.so
```

After that the installation should be finished. However I still get the same error message

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually `opencv` was successfully installed.

I had actually to change the `Path` in the `.json` file of the jupyter kernel. First I checked the list of jupyter kernel:

```
$ jupyter kernelspec list
julia-0.6    /Users/mymac/Library/Jupyter/kernels/julia-0.6
julia-1.0    /Users/mymac/Library/Jupyter/kernels/julia-1.0
python3      /Users/mymac/Library/Jupyter/kernels/python3
```

I then `cd` the above python path and, I found the file `kernel.json` inside and opened it:

```
{
 "argv": [
  "/path/to/python",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "display_name": "Python 3",
 "language": "python"
}
```

In that file, I then changed the line `/path/to/python` by the python path I got when typing the following in Terminal:

```
$ which python
/Users/mymac/anaconda3/bin/python
```

Relaunched `Atom` and it finally worked!

The hints of the [github page of jupyter](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/issues/270) helped also a lot!